# Set Function Parameters for a Variable, row/col, Matrix

Tags: c++, n-queens

So, what isn't the problem? Anyway, in attempts to solve the N Queens problem using stacks library, we were met with issues trying to set function parameters to take our matrix and manipulate it.

```
int main(){
        const int n = 8;

        bool board[n][n];
```

Here we're trying to take in the board.

```
bool isValid(int n, bool board[][], int row, int col)
```

How else could we input our matrix?

We tried using Vectors and it screwed with our calculations, ruining our progress.
We are currently trying to use dynamic arrays and pointers, but we don't understand the concept to be implemented in our scope.

Comment: This is a common problem that's the result of a wrong approach to learning C++. The right approach: open a C++ textbook to chapter 1, start reading, and following an organized curriculum that introduces and explains each topic, arranged in a logical order, progressively increasing in complexity from easy to advanced (which would explain, at some point, how to pass these kinds of parameters). The wrong approach: take a list of coding puzzles off some web site, that includes this "N-queens" problem, with the list of coding puzzles in a randomly chosen order, then attempt to hack them in C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You for some reason always assume that the goal is to learn C++. Perhaps it is not. Perhaps the goal is to solve puzzles, using C++ as a disposable forgettable tool.

Comment: If that's true, @n.m., then I would expect to read questions about random coding puzzles on the web site where these random coding puzzles are from, instead of Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm just marveling at the answer that was just posted. Sure: pass a 2D `std::array` by value to a function. That's the way to go. I'm quite open to someone convincing me that there's some value in posting endless copies of the same coding puzzle questions on Stackoverflow. But when they unintentionally result in those kinds of answers, I think that it really proves my point...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Really? I have never heard of any of those sites with random coding puzzles offering help with coding problems. People know they can get such help here so they come here. Not all of them are driven by burning desire to become better programmers and this is perfectly OK.

Comment: Move `const int n = 8;` outside of `main` to the top of your program, and use `bool board[n][n]` throughout. Do not pass `n` as a parameter to other functions. It is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the argument declaration `bool board[][]`, which is equal to `bool (*board)[]`. And C++ doesn't allow arrays without a size, the size needs to be specified by a compile-time constant.

It might be possible to use `std::array` and templates, perhaps as

```
template<std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
bool isValid(std::array<std::array<bool, N>, M> board, int row, int col);
```

where `std::array<std::array<bool, N>, M> board` corresponds to `bool board[M][N]`.

Note that `n` is no longer needed as the size is built into the arrays themselves.

Or use a global `constexpr` variable initialized to the actual size, and use that for the array sizes instead of template values.